Unable to download static content using spring boot with spring security
I need to serve a static csv file in my spring boot app so that the browser can download it from the server. As read in multiple docs, spring boot serves the content of src/main/resources by default.
I have just kept my sample-user-creation.csv file in the src/main/resources folder. Apart from that I have not added any line of code for this to work.
I am trying to download file using GET request:
http://localhost:8080/sample-user-creation.csv
but it doesn't work at all.
I have also tried setting the :
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/content/** 

and tried using:
http://localhost:8080/content/sample-user-creation.csv
This doesn't work either.
I am using spring security and also tried setting the requestMatchers explicitly for the file to permitAll() but that doesn't work either.
.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                            .requestMatchers(CorsUtils::isPreFlightRequest).permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/admin/**")
                            .hasRole("ADMIN")
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/login").permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/public/register")
                            .permitAll()
                            .requestMatchers("/sample-user-creation.csv").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        )

Why is this not working for me. All the docs say that this is a default behaviour and works without any configuration.
Am I doing anything wrong here or do I need to add any other configuration.
Adding few more details:

I am passing a valid auth token (which works for my other api) with this API too.
I have tried setting Content-Type: text/csv also in my requests.


You can't access static resources without authorization. You also didn't post a error with a particular [mcve].

@RomanC I am passing the Authorization token to the request like all my other REST calls (those are working fine). As for the minimal example. I am expected this to work out of the box by placing the file in the resources folder. I do not have any other code than the one I have pasted. I will try to share details.

You can't access static resources with the token. You should use a session to store your authorization token. So you get keeping authorized to access a static resources without a token.

I believe since I hv explicitly added request matcher to permit that path, token sud not be any issue. isnt it?

Yes, that token is the issue, remove the token an add a matcher, then it will pass a security filter.

Spring does not serve static content from the resources folder; it serves it from a folder named resources, or static, or public on the classpath.
Inside your resources folder, put a folder named static, public, or resources.  Any files then placed inside this folder will be served as static content.
So, in your case, consider adding a folder inside of /src/main/resources called, static.  Inside the static folder, add your file, sample-user-creation.csv.  Start your app and you should be able to access that file at the root of your application, http://localhost:8080/sample-user-creation.csv
If you still have the static path set, e.g. spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/content/**, it will be available at http://localhost:8080/content/sample-user-creation.csv

You're welcome.  If you think about it, you wouldn't want it to expose files out of src/main/resources, it contains your properties which will contain configuration that you don't want others to have access to.
